# How to migrate the existing structure of my angular1.6 project to angular 5/6

Tags: angular

We are migrating our existing angular1.6 project to angular 6 .I have gone through multiple angular sites but I am not able to achieve the ngupgrade.

Below is the existing project structure-

- src
- index.html
- server.js
- package.json

src-

```
-contoller
- directive
- view
- app.js
- config.router.js
```

Can anybody help to resolve this issue or help me how to proceed?

We are using UI-router for routing.

I have a wrapper of MVC for existing application. Now I want to migrate to newer version of Angular(Version 6) Since the existing application have a lot of controllers, directives, services, factories, thus I want to first ngUpgrade thereafter I will start migrating component wise.

Comment: There is a whole section / page on angular migration on the angular web site. Start there and come back if you get stuck with the specifics of where you are stuck. Please also see [ask] and provide an [mcve] if you do get stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) explains it thoroughly.

Comment: @PareshGami - **No, you don't**. If you had read the documentation on how to upgrade you would know there are ways you can implement a phased migration.

Comment: @Igor Please ask in more details i like to know the process

Comment: @PareshGami - 1) This is not my question. 2) If you want to know more about angular migration options read the [angular documentation on how to migrate](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade), it is very detailed.